# Does it cost anything just to allocate an elastic IP?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-ip

The title is pretty much self explanatory. When I click the "Allocate New Address" button in the EC2 console does it cost me anything?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is better addressed to Amazon support.

Answer (score 1):

If it's not attached to a running instance, yes, something like 0.5-1c/hour depending on the region.  See http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/